# Find original inputs $x$ and $^y$ for a given product, possible or not?

Tags: number-theory, floating-point, computer-arithmetic

$387,381,625,547,900,583,936$ is the product of this calculation $21\cdot2^{64}$.

If I only have the **product** and the **multiplier $2$** (without the exponent) would it be possible to find the other inputs used to calculate that result, where those inputs were $x = 21$ and $y = 64$?  If the answer is *no*, then might there be **special cases** where it could be possible?  Or is it simply and unequivocally impossible to know for certain, no matter what, no special cases, *period* (and it's an absurd question)?

Solve for original inputs $x$ and $y:$

$387,381,625,547,900,583,936 = x\cdot2^{y}$

Comment: $80.4 \times 2^{10} = 20.1\times 2^{12} = 1.25625 \times 2^{16}$ and other options in between. How do you choose between them?

Comment: @JasonCaldwell: The existence of several different possible inputs that give the same output means that you _cannot possibly_ "know for certain" which inputs were used to produce that output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, hinted at by the comments, is that there is not a unique choice unless you specify a way to normalize the form.

So all of the forms

$$(\underbrace{(20.1)2^{12-e}}_N)\times(2^{e})$$

are valid (where $e$ is any integer).

Normalizing would mean, for example, requiring that $0\leq N<2$. That would determine $N$ and $e$ uniquely ($N=1.25625$ and $e=16$).

Comment: Glad to help.${}{}{}{}$